# Rebuild Flutter widget when shared_preferences value is updated

Tags: flutter, widget

I would like to create a widget whose apperance depends on a value that its saved in the device through shared_preferences plugin. How can i rebuild the widget every time that this values changes. Im trying to use StreamBuilder but i don’t know if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Streams is a good solution.

Take a look at reactive programming libaries or blog posts:

- Libraries:

  - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc
  - https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart
- Some blogs posts:

  - https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-reactive-and-persistent-flutter-app-using-streams-4d6b947c5cb5
  - https://stacksecrets.com/flutter/working-with-bloc-using-reactive-programming
  - https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming-streams-bloc/

Comment: Yes, and ff reactive doesn't suit your app, you can take a look at this: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 0):

You could look into StreamingSharedPreferences: https://github.com/roughike/streaming_shared_preferences

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Could also use a StreamBuilder here.
  return PreferenceBuilder<int>(
    preference: preferences.getInt('counter', defaultValue: 0),
    builder: (BuildContext context, int counter) {
      return Text('Button pressed $counter times!');
    }
  );
}
```

somewhere else in your code:

```
preferences.setInt('counter', 5);
```

This will automatically trigger a rebuild.